# Someone help me decode this

Tags: hash, md5, sha256

What type of hash is this? 
a9df6dcd35f4e7223ff3dd087abcc266

I can't find anything when I decrypt it. 
Please someone decrypt it

Comment: For starters, you don't decrypt hashes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the length of the text it could be one of the following hash formats:

- DomainCachedCredentials
- Haval128
- MD2
- MD4
- MD5
- NTLM

But (because it is a hash, a one way function) you can't decrypt it. You can try to brute force it, but this will possibly take a very long time. All the rainbow tables I know were unable to identify the original value, perhaps it was salted.

Comment: There's also an infinite amount of strings that has that exact hash.  So chances are you brute force the wrong string.

Comment: @OskarSkog It's not actually infinite, at least not for MD4, MD5, and NTLM. Those use a final padding block which encodes in it a 64-bit representation of the size of the data to be hashed. Because of that, they can only take in 2^64 bits of data, and obviously you can't fit an infinite set in that.

Comment: Aha, I guess I've learned something new today.   OP will be relieved to hear that once he exceeds lengths of 2306 PB he can stop brute forcing :-)